Clarification on Calculations for $v_{1,z} $ in "A Method for Verifying the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis"
I am reading the paper "A Method for Verifying the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis" by Ghaith A. Hiary, Summer Ireland, and Megan Kyi. On page 18, $ v_{1,z} $ is calculated using Corollary 9 and Lemma 10 with parameters $ K = 10^7 $, $ z = 10^{28} + 501675.8 $, and $ x = -2 $. The result given is $ \operatorname{Re}(v_{1,z}) \in [31.418062, 31.41806] $.
The definitions used are as follows:

Corollary 9 states:
$
  v_{1,z} = -\frac{1}{2} \log(\pi) + \frac{1}{2} \psi\left(\frac{3-z}{2}\right) + \frac{g'(1-z)}{g(1-z)},
  $
where $ \psi $ is the digamma function.

Lemma 10 gives an approximation for $ g'(1-z) / g(1-z) $:
$
  \frac{g'(1-z)}{g(1-z)} = -\frac{1}{z} - \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\Lambda(k)}{k^{1-z}} + R(K,x),
  $
with the error term $ R(K,x) $ bounded as
$
  |R(K,x)| \leq \frac{K^x}{x} \left( 2.85 \frac{2x-1}{\log(K)} - 1 \right)
  $.


I attempted to reproduce the calculation using MATLAB. Below is my implementation and results:

Attempt to Calculate $ \psi $ (Digamma Function)
% Define the complex number
z = -2 + (10^28 + 501675.8)*1i;
s = (3-z)/2;

% Euler-Mascheroni constant
gamma = 0.57721566490153286060651209;

% Number of terms in the series
N = 1e5; % Adjust as needed for precision

% Compute the series sum
series_sum = 0;
for n = 0:N
    series_sum = series_sum + (1/(n+1) - 1/(n+s));
end

% Compute the digamma value
digamma_value = -gamma + series_sum;

disp(['Digamma value at z = ', num2str(real(s)), ' + ', num2str(imag(s)), 'i is: ', num2str(digamma_value)]);

Result:
$
\psi\left(\frac{3-z}{2}\right) \approx 11.5129 - 2.00002 \times 10^{-23}i
$

Calculate $R(K, x) $
K = 10^7;
R = -(K^(-2))/2 * (2.85*(-5)/log(K) - 1);
disp(R);

Result:
$
R(K, x) \approx 9.4205 \times 10^{-15}
$

Approximate $ \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\Lambda(k)}{k^{1-z}}$
K = 10^7;

% Initialize the sum
sum_value = 0;

% Loop through k from 1 to K
for k = 1:K
    % Calculate the Mangoldt function for k
    L_k = mangoldt(k);
    
    % Add the term to the sum
    sum_value = sum_value + L_k / k^(1 - (10^28 + 501675.8)*1i + 2);
end

disp(sum_value);

% Define the smallest_prime_factor function
function p = smallest_prime_factor(n)
    for p = 2:sqrt(n)
        if mod(n, p) == 0
            return; % Return the first divisor
        end
    end
    p = n; % If no divisor is found, n is prime
end

% Define the Mangoldt function
function L = mangoldt(n)
    if n == 1
        L = 0; % Von Mangoldt function is 0 for n = 1
    else
        % Find the smallest prime factor of n
        p = smallest_prime_factor(n);
        
        % Check if n is a power of p
        k = log(n) / log(p);
        if abs(k - round(k)) < 1e-10 % Tolerance for floating-point errors
            L = log(p); % Logarithm of the prime
        else
            L = 0; % Not a prime power
        end
    end
end

Result:
$
\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\Lambda(k)}{k^{1-z}} \approx -0.0509 - 0.0094i
$

Final Computation for $ v_{1,z} $
Using the components calculated above:
v = -0.5*log(pi) - 1/(-2 + (10^28 + 501675.8)*1i) + 0.0509 + 0.0094i + (9.4205e-15) + 0.5*(11.5129 - 2.00002e-23i);
disp(v);

Result:
$
v \approx 5.2350 + 0.0094i
$

My result does not match the range provided in the paper ($ \operatorname{Re}(v_{1,z}) \in [31.418062, 31.41806] $). Could someone help identify where my calculations or implementation might be incorrect? Additionally, are there specific precision considerations or assumptions in the paper that I may have overlooked?
